# Can someone what kin of audio input that is

Tags: electrical, connectors, audio

[image]

Can someone tell me what kind of audio connection that is.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what kind of device it is. What is this thing?

Comment: easy: a proprietary one.

Answer (score 1):

It is a 13 pin 3.5mm aux input or din connector 3$ on eBay To stereo just the plug 2$ the 3.5mm is important as there are many different sizes of 13 pin connectors.

Answer (score 0):

That is a 13 pin DIN connector.